# Valgrind errors in C : using structures, linked list and pointers. Invalid read of size 1 and Process terminating with default action of signal 11

Tags: c, valgrind

so i'm writing a program that should link data structures in a linked list, but i always get the valgrind errors :

```
Invalid read of size 1
and
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
 Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
```

a big part of the code was already given to me, and i only need to complete it.
this is what i'm asked to do:

**Reading the roads :**
Write the code to read the roads and connect the information about the roads to the
cities. The roads are specified by a begin city and an end city, both of which are defined
with the name of the city, followed by the road length.
First, it needs to be determined for every road which structures represent the begin
city and the end city.
Use the function new_road() from road.h to create a Road structure.The structure returned by new_road() shall be added to the roads list of the city in which the road departs, similar to the
way a City structure is added to the list of cities.
Please note that you are only allowed to make changes to roadplan.c

**here is the main file of the program, with the part I've written preceded with a FIXME comment:**

**The error message is all the way at the bottom**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "salloc.h"
#include "city.h"
#include "road.h"

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 100



/*
 * Build the map datastructure
 */
static City *create_map (FILE *data_file)
{
    int num_of_cities, i = 0;
    int num_of_roads = 0;
    City *map = NULL;

    /* Read in city-names   */
    fscanf (data_file, "%d", &num_of_cities);

    for (i = 0; i < num_of_cities; i++)
    {
        char city_name[MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1];
        City *city;
        City *c;

        fscanf (data_file, "%s", city_name);

        if (find_city (map, city_name) != NULL)
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "City %s already on the map\n", city_name);
            delete_map (map);
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        city = new_city (safe_strdup (city_name));

        if (map == NULL)
            /* This is the first city of the map */
            map = city;
        else {
            /* Find last of city list */
            c = map;
            while (c->next) c = c->next;
            /* And append new city there */
            c -> next = city;
        }
    }

       /* FIXME
         * Read number of roads
         * For each road:
         *    Read origin city name, destination city name and length
         *    Find pointers to orgin city structure and destination city structure
         *    using the function find_city()
         *    Create new road structure using new_road() function
         *    Add it to the list of roads of the origin city.
         */

    /* Read in number-of roads  */
    fscanf (data_file, "%d", &num_of_roads);
    /*read origin city name, destination city name and length for each road
    */
    for (i = 0; i < num_of_roads; i++)
    {
        City road_origin[MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1]={{0}}, road_destination[MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1]={{0}};
        unsigned int length = 1;
        Road *road;
        Road *r;
        City *city;
        fscanf (data_file, "%s %s %u", road_origin->name, road_destination->name, &length);
        if (find_city (map, road_origin->name) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "Cannot find city %s on the map\n", road_origin->name);
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (find_city (map, road_destination->name) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "Cannot find city %s on the map\n", road_destination->name);
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        road = new_road(road_origin,road_destination, length);
       /*Create new road structure using new_road() function
         *    Add it to the list of roads of the origin city.
         */
        for (city = map; city != NULL; city = city->next)
        {
            if (strcmp(city->name,road_origin->name)==0)
            {
                road_origin->name = city->name;
                if (city->roads == NULL)
                    city->roads=road;/*first road of that city*/
                else
                {
                    r=road;
                    while (r->next) r = r->next;
                    r -> next = road;
                }
            }
            if (strcmp(city->name,road_destination->name)==0)
            {
                road_destination->name = city->name;
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}

/*
 * Locate city with name city_name on the map
 */
City *find_city (City *list_of_cities, char *city_name)
{
    City *c = list_of_cities;
    while (c != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp (c->name, city_name) == 0)
            return c;
        c = c->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

/*
 * Delete a map
 */
static void delete_map (City *map)
{
    City *map_copy;
    while (map != NULL)
    {
        map_copy = map;
        map = map->next;
        delete_city (map_copy);
    }
}
```

here are the given .c and .h files

road.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "road.h"
#include "salloc.h"

Road *new_road (City *origin, City *destination, int length)
{
     Road *road     = safe_malloc (sizeof (Road));

     road->origin       = origin;
     road->destination  = destination;
     road->length       = length;
     road->next     = NULL;

     return road;
}


void delete_road (Road *road)
{
    if (road != NULL)
        free (road);
}


void delete_roads (Road *roads)
{
    Road *roads_copy;

    while (roads)
    {
            roads_copy = roads;
        roads = roads->next;
        delete_road (roads_copy);
    }
}
```

road.h:

```
#ifndef _ROAD_H_
#define _ROAD_H_

typedef struct road Road;

#include "city.h"

struct road
{
    City        *origin;
    City        *destination;
    unsigned int    length;
    Road        *next;
};

Road *new_road (City *origin, City *destination, int length);
void delete_road (Road *road);
void delete_roads (Road *roads);

#endif /* _ROAD_H_ */
```

city.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "city.h"
#include "salloc.h"

City    *new_city (char *name)
{
    City *city      = safe_malloc (sizeof (City));

    city->name      = name;
    city->roads     = NULL;
    city->next      = NULL;

    return city;
}


void delete_city (City *city)
{
    if (city != NULL)
    {
        delete_roads (city->roads); 
        free (city->name);
        free (city);
    }
}
```

city.h:

```
#ifndef _CITY_H_
#define _CITY_H_

typedef struct city City;

#include "road.h"

struct city
{
    char    *name;
    Road    *roads;
    City    *next;
};


City *new_city (char *name);
void delete_city (City *city);
City *find_city (City *map, char *name);

#endif /*_CITY_H_ */
```

salloc.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void *check_pointer (void *p)
{
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Error: out of memory!\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    return p;
}

void *safe_malloc (size_t size)
{
    return check_pointer (malloc (size));
}


char *safe_strdup (const char *string)
{
    return strcpy (safe_malloc (strlen (string) + 1), string);
}
```

salloc.h:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

/* These functions provide a way to safely
 * allocate memory
 */

void *safe_malloc (size_t size);
char *safe_strdup (const char *string);
```

**Here is the error message I got :**

```
Non-zero exitcode 139
********** runguard stderr follows **********
/usr/bin/runguard: warning: command terminated with signal 11
********** valgrind output follows **********
Memcheck, a memory error detector
Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
Command: /var/lib/domjudge/judgings/ce-codeserver/c8-s38522-j44168/testcase001/execdir/program_d datafile

Invalid read of size 1
   at 0x4C2E2B4: __strcmp_sse42 (vg_replace_strmem.c:852)
   by 0x400B91: find_city (roadplan.c:27)
   by 0x400DEB: create_map (roadplan.c:123)
   by 0x401246: main (roadplan.c:280)
 Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd


Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
 Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
   at 0x4C2E2B4: __strcmp_sse42 (vg_replace_strmem.c:852)
   by 0x400B91: find_city (roadplan.c:27)
   by 0x400DEB: create_map (roadplan.c:123)
   by 0x401246: main (roadplan.c:280)
 If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
 overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
 possible), you can try to increase the size of the
 main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
 The main thread stack size used in this run was 16777216.

HEAP SUMMARY:
    in use at exit: 176 bytes in 11 blocks
  total heap usage: 11 allocs, 0 frees, 176 bytes allocated

LEAK SUMMARY:
   definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
   indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
     possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
   still reachable: 176 bytes in 11 blocks
        suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory

For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: `}while (city_name != 0);` <<-- always true (apart from the types) Also: don't use (f)scanf("%s", ...)` to read strings, your input may get clogged.

Comment: The error suggests that one of the strings passed to `strcmp` in `find_city` is a NULL pointer (`Address 0x0`).  Now to figure out why.  I think you need to fire up your debugger and start stepping through the code.  It won't be possible for anyone to help you further than that because you haven't included the input which causes the problem.  Anyway, this is a rather large volume of code to ask people to help you debug - a [mcve] would be much nicer.

Comment: @NateEldredge ok, thanks for this answer. I will also try to write a minimized version of my code my post. should i edit it, or should I delete it and create a new one with minimized code or should i leave this one while I create the minimized code?

Comment: I would suggest editing this one.  If you want you can temporarily delete it, and then undelete after the edits are made, but it's not necessary.

Comment: @wildplasser my goal is that the while loop doesn't stop before a 0 is entered as input, does my function work like that? also, what function should I use? those are the only ones I learned in my courses until now. thanks for the answer.

Comment: City_name is a character array so it (its address) will never be zero.

Comment: Explaining things like this: `if (strcmp(city->name,road_origin->name)==0) { road_origin->name = city->name;` to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would probably help to a degree. Given `name` is a `char*`, this is a recipe for (a) memory leaks, and (b) double-frees. Anyway best of luck.